# User token from Azure B2C Tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have to migrate users from an Azure Active Directory B2C Tenant (oldtenant) to another (newtenant) using [Seamless migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration)

In the oldtenant I have some "users" (with @oldtenant.onmicrosoft.com) and some "Azure AD B2C users" (with @otherdomain.com).

The "Users" are created with button [image]

The "Azure AD B2C users" are created with button [image]

I have to retrieve the user access token to check the user's credential to create the user in the newtenant.
I used the source code provided [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/tree/master/seamless-account-migration/source-code/Contoso.AADB2C.API) to create an API that uses user's credential to retrieve the user token.
I Also create in the oldtenant an app registration to allow the API to access user's info.

When I try to retrieve user token for @oldtenant.onmicrosoft.com it works, but when I try to retrieve the token for an user @otherdomain.com, I obtain the following error:

```
error_description: "AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the oldtenant.onmicrosoft.com directory. To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.Trace ID: 74d2a027-7011-4ee5-b62e-d022dd861d06.Correlation ID: 07427a5b-494a-44e7-947d-40eb5a4aee66.Timestamp: 2021-05-07 10:22:58Z"
```

It should work but, I used the code provided by the documentation. I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a consumer account (B2C account) by using "Create Azure AD B2C user" button, the real user principle name should be like this: `{objectID}@oldtenant.onmicrosoft.com` although you can sign into B2C with such a mail format `xxx@otherdomain.com`.

The data in the background is actually in this format:

```
{
    "id": "d5342d11-67e0-46ed-865b-20e3138ecf1f",
    "creationType": "LocalAccount",
    "userPrincipalName": "eb37ce98-8461-4f9b-ab57-e6ebb3b791c6@allentest001.onmicrosoft.com",
    "identities": [
        {
            "signInType": "emailAddress",
            "issuer": "allentest001.onmicrosoft.com",
            "issuerAssignedId": "allen3@jmaster.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        {
            "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
            "issuer": "allentest001.onmicrosoft.com",
            "issuerAssignedId": "eb37ce98-8461-4f9b-ab57-e6ebb3b791c6@allentest001.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

In this example, I can sign into B2C with `allen3@jmaster.onmicrosoft.com`, but when I need to get the user access token, I need to use `eb37ce98-8461-4f9b-ab57-e6ebb3b791c6@allentest001.onmicrosoft.com`.

B2C authentication is different from AAD authentication. And to call Microsoft Graph, we need to use AAD authentication (B2C authentication is not supported to call Microsoft Graph).

In this case, `eb37ce98-8461-4f9b-ab57-e6ebb3b791c6@allentest001.onmicrosoft.com` is the UPN you need to use to get user token and call Microsoft Graph.

So you should list your B2C consumer users to find their `userPrincipalName`s first so that you could take next actions.

You can [list B2C consumer users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) easily.

Comment: Yes I was looking for the "identities" field to get the UPN.I add the code for Microsoft Graph SDK query.
`string fs = string.Format("userPrincipalName eq '{0}'", username);
var su = await client.Users.Request().Filter(fs).Select("identities,userPrincipalName").GetAsync();`
`if (su.Count() == 0)
{
 fs = string.Format("identities/any(id:id/issuer eq '{0}' and id/issuerAssignedId eq '{1}')", tenant, username);
 su = await client.Users.Request().Filter(fs).Select("identities,userPrincipalName").GetAsync();
}`
`if (su.Count() != 0)
{
 userUpn = su.FirstOrDefault().UserPrincipalName;
}`